# population of ants is given $P(t) = 100 e^{0.3t}$ where $t$ is days. Find rate of change in population when $t = 3$ and $t = 9$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The population, $P(t)$, of rare Brazilian ants is given by $P(t) = 100e^{0.3t}$ where $t$ is in days. Find the rate of change in population when $t = 3$ and $t = 9$.
What would be answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

The word " The rate of change " refers to the derivative. So the question asks you to calculate the derivative of $P(t)$ when $t = 3,9$ respectively. Hence $P'(t) = 0.3\times 100e^{0.3t}\implies P'(3)= 30\times e^{0.3\cdot 3}= 30\times e^{0.9}\approx 73.79$. In other words, the population increases at a rate of about $74$ person per day on the third day of the experiment. The other one is done in the same way.

Comment: Hi, first of thank you very much for responding. Can you please explain completely for what i have to do so get towards the answer, Im a bit lost. thanks again

Comment: @RestiveToast: Hello there. Please see my edited explanation.

Comment: got it, once again thank you very much

Comment: @RestiveToast: Sure, any time...